# How to Connect internet through wifi from terminal in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, wireless-networking

I had recently installed ubuntu sever 12.04 on my Lenovo laptop. As a first task i was tying to connect to wifi through it. Since there is no GUI the task is to be done through terminal. I was following these steps to acomplish the task.

1. sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
2. sudo iwlist wlan0 scan : Scanning the list of wifi access points available
3. sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid ACCES_POINT key s:LOGIN_KEY
4. dhclient wlan0

But the above procedure gives error on the step 3.
The error is:
Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) :
    SET failed on device eth1 ; Invalid argument.

I can't understand where i am getting wrong.

Thanx in advance.

p.s.: Currently posting from Ubuntu 12.04 desktop edition. :D

Comment: Please provide me link to the already answered post like this.... thnx..

Comment: I agree with @KristopherMicinski, try superuser, it is off topic on so.

Comment: ok.... me changing the tag..

Comment: You are doing things wrong maybe you should try to do `/etc/init.d/networking restart`